# CSS: Can't alter css class within a div

Tags: css, nested

I have been working on this for about 45 minutes and I'm sure the answer is ridiculously easy, I'm just not getting it. I need to take out the width element of `.content` (width:760px). However, when I change the CSS (it's a wordpress.com site, which is why I have to use the customizer and can't just do this via the editor) it just ADDS a content class and doesn't change the one in the stylesheet.

This is what's in the stylesheet, the site uses the content-sidebar-wrap style:

```
/* Wrapping div for .content and .sidebar-primary */

.content-sidebar-sidebar .content-sidebar-wrap,
.sidebar-content-sidebar .content-sidebar-wrap,
.sidebar-sidebar-content .content-sidebar-wrap {
    width: 930px;
}

.content-sidebar-sidebar .content-sidebar-wrap {
    float: left;
}

.sidebar-content-sidebar .content-sidebar-wrap,
.sidebar-sidebar-content .content-sidebar-wrap {
    float: right;
}

/* Content */

.content {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 760px;
}
```

Comment: So do you want to change the width from 930px to 760px?

Comment: No, It's a 2-column layout, I have already taken out the sidebar with a display:none (that was on the left). I want to take out the .content width: 760 to make it full width, but it will add a style instead of recognizing it. This is the site (and page): http://www.srlifesolutionsllc.com/about/

Comment: If it were wordpress.org, I would have just coded a new page template, but I have to do it css as it's .com. Cannot for the life of me figure out what I need to add to the .content! I have tried everything, I feel like.

Comment: ah, then in your "customize web" tab, try putting this `.content { width: initial !important; }` ... Then the 760px width would be taken out I think

Comment: Did you try changing width to width:100%? Also note, there is a wordpress-specific stackexhange here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/. You also may want to try to track down the style.css file in wp-content and then make this modification.

Comment: Oh, you are very wonderful. THANK YOU. I would not at all have thought to do that and would have only been focusing on eliminating the 760. I hope I can remember this for when it happens in the future. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Thanks, Dream_Cap. For some odd reason, I cannot see the editor under appearance and I don't have ftp at this time (can you have ftp access wiht wordpress.com? I assume that's why I don't see the editor). It's a pain.

Comment: Also, samAlvin, how do I say you answered it? I don't see a button. Sorry, complete newb to this site!

Comment: @ingcol Glad it solved your problem :) .. I've moved my comment to an answer, the "mark as answer" button will be shown beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a wordpress.com site, not wordpress.org, we can alter the CSS in the "customize web" tab.

In your "customize web" tab, try putting this:

```
.content {
    width: initial !important;
}
```

Then the 760px width would be taken out.